# Multiline Matlab comments in package Listings

Tags: listings, comments, matlab

I am using the package listings to include some Matlab code in my report.
It works well with comments beginning by `%` but does not recognise multiline comments `%{ ... %}`:

```
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{language=Matlab}
...
\begin{lstlisting}
% normal comment
MATLAB code
%{
This is
a multiline
comment
%}
function [x,y] = test(x)
\end{lstlisting}
```

gives

[image]

instead of

[image]

in Matlab.

How can I change `\lstset` to make it work?

Comment: Check out http://texdoc.net/pkg/matlab-prettifier It's a package based on `listings` with several improvements for MATLAB code, including block comment support.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My recommendation would be to use the package [`matlab-prettifier`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/matlab-prettifier), which is based on `listings` but provides enhanced features for MATLAB code above and beyond those provided by `listings`' `Matlab` language definition (including support for block comments):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{matlab-prettifier}
\lstset{style=Matlab-editor}

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}
% normal comment
MATLAB code
%{
This is
a multiline
comment
%}
function [x,y] = test(x)
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If, for some reason, you must use `listings` with its existing implementation of the `Matlab` language, you can add support for block comments by setting the package's `morecomment` key:

```
morecomment=[s]{\%\{}{\%\}}
```

Here, `[s]` signifies that we are looking for two delimiters, the first to open a block comment and the second to close it. The following brace groups contain the opening and closing delimiters for a block comment, respectively. Note that both the percent sign and the individual open/close braces must be escaped by backslashes when defining the comment delimiters.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{
  language=Matlab,
  basicstyle=\ttfamily,
  morecomment=[s]{\%\{}{\%\}},
}

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}
% normal comment
MATLAB code
%{
This is
a multiline
comment
%}
function [x,y] = test(x)
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! I will use the second solution, as I find hard to change the font and font size of matlab-prettifier to make it look like normal listings. But I keep in mind that this package is useful for Matlab code in Latex.

Comment: @fidekild I'm the author of `matlab-prettifier`. Sadly, the API of the package isn't ideal, in part because it inherits some unfortunate (IMO) design decisions from the `listings` API. In order to change the font family and/or font size without losing existing settings, users have to reach into the package's internals, which is pretty bad. I've been playing with the idea of improving the API, but I'm also wary of making it too different from `listings`', which would be a barrier to adoption. Anyway, don't hesitate to ask another question about the problem you're having with the font.

Comment: @Jubobs Thank you very much for your explanation about your package. The solution of Paul Gessier is working very well in my case, but I thank you a lot for your very good package that I use in other Latex files now.