# how to force several lines/commands to appear as regular text?

Tags: formatting

I am trying to convince Overleaf to display several lines of copy-pasted MATLAB code as regular text. I do not think screengrabbing images of the code looks professional so I am trying in earnest to format the MATLAB code to look in my LaTeX document similar to how it would in the MATLAB environment. For now I am most concerned with preventing Overleaf from thinking any part of the MATLAB code is a LaTeX command. I found a workaround for indenting, but the "\textregular" command isn't working to prevent error messages and formatting issues. I would like to color certain strings of text if possible (I am sure that it is) but it is not essential.

Please note that I have been looking to see if anybody addressed this already and if they have, I must not have been looking in the right place. However, I spent more than a little time looking. Thank you in advance for all help but please, there is no need for anybody to gloat about their 'sick formatting skills' or point out my already obvious inexperience. Thank you again.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) You might want to have a look at the [tag:listings] package. Also you find a lot of questions here on TeX.SX dealing with this topic, e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/313738/95441.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Use `matlab-prettifier` package with MATLAB code put in `lstlisting` environment.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[]{IEEEtran}


\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{bigfoot}

\usepackage[]{matlab-prettifier}
% The packages above allow for printing MATLAB-like format of codes when using the command "\begin{lstlisting}"

    % MATLAB Pretifying Options
    \lstset{
                % Style
                style = Matlab-editor, % default style for matlab pretification
                basicstyle = \mlttfamily, % Bera Mono font
                escapechar = ", % character to escape matlab pretification mode. This value should be " because " is not allowed in MATLAB
                %
                % Section rulers
                mlshowsectionrules = true, % horizontal rules above section titles (default: false)
                mlsectionrulethickness = 0.08, % thickness of horizontal lines above section titles (default: 0.05)
                mlsectionrulecolor = black!25, % color of horizontal rules above section titles (default: black!15)
        }



\begin{document}


\title{Development of a Generalized PV Model in MATLAB/Simulink Using Datasheet Values}


% Authors names and emails
\author{Al-Motasem I. Aldaoudeyeh
    % Information about the authors (in the margins)
    \thanks{Al-Motasem I. Aldaoudeyeh is with the Department of Electrical and Computer Engineering, North Dakota State University, Fargo, ND, 58102 USA. email: almotasem.aldaoudeye@ndsu.edu}
}

\maketitle


\appendix
A MATLAB code to find the parameters $K_{p}$ and $\beta$ is given below:
\begin{lstlisting}[]
%% Wind Turbine Data (GEV MP R 275 KW)

% Cut-in speed an rated power
v_ci = 4; P_r_WT = 275e3;

% Rotor diameter
D = 32;


% === Power speed data ===

% GCR wind speeds and their corresponding outputs
v_w_GCR = 4:12;
P_e_WT_GCR = [3 18 36 58 98 141 189 243 275]*1e3;

% The swept area
A = (D/2)^2 * pi;

%% Fitting The Parameters

% Fitting options
options =
fitoptions('Method', 'NonlinearLeastSquares', 'Lower',[0.5, 1], 'Upper',[500, 4], 'StartPoint',[50, 3]);


% === Exponential fit equation ===
ft =
fittype( '1/2 * rho_n * A * K_p * (x^beta - v_ci^beta)', 'problem', {'rho_n', 'A','v_ci'}, 'options', options);

% Do the fitting
fit_model =
fit( v_w_GCR', P_e_WT_GCR', ft, 'problem', {rho_n, A, v_ci} );
\end{lstlisting}




\end{document}
```