# Have listing package recognize Matlab comments coming after "..."

Tags: listings, comments, matlab

In Matlab, `...` means that a statement is continued on the next
physical line.  Any text coming *after* the `...` is a comment.
**Is there any way to have the `listing` package recognize the comments
coming after `...`?**

In the following minimal working example, comments are made blue.
However, only the comments prefixed by `%` are made blue. Comments
coming after `...` are not.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{listings}
\begin{document}
\lstset{language=Matlab,frame=single,
        basicstyle=\ttfamily\small,
        commentstyle=\color{blue}\ttfamily\small}
\begin{lstlisting}
   % A comment
   disp('Hello world') % A comment
   disp( ...A comment after triple dots
         ... Another comment after triple dots
      'Hello world' )
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

If there is a quick way to do this with the listings package, I would
likely prefer that than to explore another package, e.g., the
[matlab-prettifier](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/matlab-prettifier), as
suggested
[here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/313738/multiline-matlab-comments-in-package-listings).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, for reasons the `otherkeywords` mechanism isn't necessary for comments. So the correct way to get what you want seems to be:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{listings}
\begin{document}
\lstset{language=Matlab,frame=single,
        basicstyle=\ttfamily\small,
        commentstyle=\color{blue}\ttfamily\small,
        morecomment=[l]{...},
        }
\begin{lstlisting}
   % A comment
   disp('Hello world') % A comment
   disp( ...A comment after triple dots
         ... Another comment after triple dots
      'Hello world' )
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, Skillmon.